# Does $f_{X+Y}(z) = E[f_Y(z-X)]$ hold?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, convolution

Let $X,Y$ be independent real random variables, with $Y$ having a pdf. The following statement is true if $X$ also has a pdf (it is just the standard convolution integral written as an expectation):

$$f_{X+Y}(z) = E[f_Y(z-X)]$$

However, intuitively speaking, it does not seem like $X$ has to have a pdf for this to hold. Is it true? If so, can you give a reference or a proof?

Comment: Hint: just replace $f_X(x)dx$ with $dF_X(x)$ in the integral defining the convolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement
$$f_{X+Y}(z) = E[f_Y(z-X)]$$ for almost all $z$ is equivalent to $$\int _A f_{X+Y}(z)dz = \int _A E[f_Y(z-X)]dz$$ fro al measurable sets $A$. LHS is $$P( X+Y \in A).$$ By Fubini's Theorem RHS is $$E\left[\int_A f_Y(z-X)\right]dz$$ which is nothing but $$E[P(Y \in  A-X)].$$ The desired equality now follows by independence of $X$ and $Y$.